# Return all the lines in a file after "chomp"ing them

Tags: perl, subroutine

I have a subroutine that is used to read the contents of a file, line by line. Is it possible to continue the process instead of returning only one line?

```
sub read_lines {
    my ($file) = @_;
    if (open(my $fh, "<", $file)) {
        while (my $data = <$fh>)  {
            chomp ($data);
            return $data;   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you would have seen the mistake yourself if you indented your code.

Comment: What's wrong with `my @lines = <$fh>; chomp @lines;`?

Comment: It returns the values as integers -_- and returns only one value.

Comment: Then there's something else going on here. How are you using the `@lines` array?

Comment: It returns only one line because you are using a return statement inside a while loop.So it returns only one line.Store all the lines into array and then return them at the end of subroutine(not in while loop).

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to have all the lines of the file in an array, you can also write it like this:

```
sub read_lines {
    my $file = shift;
    if (open(my $fh, "<", $file)) {
        my @lines = <$fh>;
        chomp(@lines);
        close $fh;
        return @lines;
    } else {
        die "Failed to open Filehandle for '$file': $!\n";
    }
}
```

or using File::Slurp (faster):

```
use File::Slurp;
my @lines = read_file($file);
chomp(@lines);
```

Comment: The lexical file handle ($fh) will automatically close when the subroutine exists, because the $fh has gone out of scope. But an unclosed file handle feels like walking out of my house without my trousers on. :D And it's just good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t return from inside the loop. vOv

```
sub read_lines {
    my $file = shift;
    my @result = ();
    if (open(my $fh, "<", $file)) {
        while (<$fh>) {
            chomp;
            push @result, $_;
        }
    }
    @result;
}

my @lines = read_lines($file);
```

Or a shorter equivalent.

```
sub read_lines {
    my $file = shift;
    open(my $fh, "<", $file) or return;
    my @lines = <$fh>;
    chomp @lines;
    return @lines;
}        

my @lines = read_lines($file);
```

Comment: The file has a list of names(about 100), when I use this subroutine, it reads them as integers.

Comment: @user2524169, Sounds like you're calling `read_lines` in scalar context, when it returns a *list* of lines as requested.

Comment: @user2524169 That doesn't make sense. Can you explain more clearly what you mean ?

Comment: I have a text file, which has 100 usernames, for example:

username1
username2
username3
username4
username5

Comment: I need to read each username, line by line. For example http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4S438N1Y in that order, and then I would use each of those names for another purpose.